# Splitting string multiple times and return the result as new DataFrame

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to split a pandas column repeatedly. I want to find the string in-between two strings, indefinitely.  For example, lets say i have the pandas column from the input below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data=np.array([["'abc'ad32kn'def'dfannasfl[]12a'ghi'"],
              ["'jk'adf%#d1asn'lm'dfas923231sassda"],
              ["'nop'ad&@*-0'qrs'd2&*@^#!!sda'tuv'dasdj_23'w'823a&@'xyz'adfa"]])

df = pd.DataFrame({'Practice Column': data.ravel()})

print(df)
```

I then, would  like to split these string by opening and closing quotes `'...'`, and then take what is inside.  So, my final output would be:

[image]

Can someone help me out?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use `extractall` here:

```
df['Practice Column'].str.extractall(r"'(.*?)'").unstack(1)[0].fillna('')

match    0    1    2  3    4
0      abc  def  ghi        
1       jk   lm             
2      nop  qrs  tuv  w  xyz
```

The pattern `'(.*?)'` finds all instances of strings within the single quotes. More info -

```
'      # Match opening quote
(      # Open capture group
.*?    # Non-greedy match for anything
)      # End of capture group
'      # Match closing quote
```

To merge this back with `df`, you can either use `join`:

```
v = df.join(df['Practice Column']
    .str.extractall(r"'(.*?)'").unstack(1)[0].fillna(''))
```

Or, assign "Practice Column" back:

```
v = df['Practice Column'].str.extractall(r"'(.*?)'").unstack(1)[0].fillna('')
v.insert(0, 'Practice Column', df['Practice Column'])
```

```
print(v)

match                                    Practice Column    0    1    2  3    4
a                    'abc'ad32kn'def'dfannasfl[]12a'ghi'  abc  def  ghi        
b                     'jk'adf%#d1asn'lm'dfas923231sassda   jk   lm             
c      'nop'ad&@*-0'qrs'd2&*@^#!!sda'tuv'dasdj_23'w'8...  nop  qrs  tuv  w  xyz
```

---

Another solution with a list comprehension (for performance).

```
import re

p = re.compile("'(.*?)'")    
pd.DataFrame([
    p.findall(s) for s in df['Practice Column']]).fillna('')

     0    1    2  3    4
0  abc  def  ghi        
1   jk   lm             
2  nop  qrs  tuv  w  xyz
```

This won't work if there are NaNs, so here's a modified version of the solution above. You will need to drop the NaNs first.

```
pd.DataFrame([
    p.findall(s) for s in df['Practice Column'].dropna()]
).fillna('')

     0    1    2  3    4
0  abc  def  ghi        
1   jk   lm             
2  nop  qrs  tuv  w  xyz
```

Comment: Thats it. Thanks.  I can't accept it as the solution in under twelve minutes the site said, but I will asap. Can you take a second to explain the r"'(.*?)'". I believe that is regex.

Comment: @J.Dykstra Have edited some explanation into the answer.

Comment: Does this retain order? As in, if i merge back on to get my original practice column, am i able to basically just set them next to eachother?

Comment: @J.Dykstra The simplicity of the resulting solution depends on whether your column has NaNs. Is this possible?

Comment: There is no NaNs in the data.

Comment: @J.Dykstra Okay, see edit. Hopefully that should be the end of your follow ups ;-) If not, feel free to open another question.

Comment: ahaha thanks! My bad! I don't mean to pester! have a good day!

Comment: @J.Dykstra Not at all.